# How do I install python dependency modules through bamboo

Tags: python, module, bamboo

I am trying to run a python program through bamboo.

How do I install python dependency modules through bamboo
I need to install some python modules like flask , xldr etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Remote or log into the Bamboo agent and manually install the modules.  This is a one time install and then they will be there for the task to use in the future.
2. Run the job using a Docker host instead of the local agent.  Then you can specify all the dependencies in the Docker image that is used to build (e.g., Python version, imports).

Comment: I don't want to use docker.

Comment: @VineeshTP: Then your best option will be to install those packages on the Bamboo agent.

Comment: I am trying to use pip to install dependencies. I am able to access python but, couldn't get the pip from the script task.

Comment: I hope we can install the dependencies through the shell commands. So that I can run as tasks

Comment: Try adding PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin" to the Environment variables.  Bamboo runs in a semi-sandboxed area so when you pip installed the packages they most likely installed as your user path, not the environment path Bamboo is using.

Comment: I can access python with out add the environment  variable in bamboo

Comment: Python should be accessible but you'll need to add the environment variable to access the packages installed with pip.

Comment: Also we can do the dependencies are task in bamboo. Add the modules in a text file and can be able to run with pip.